# How to understand "forgive sb for something / doing something"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> She'd find a way to ***forgive him for the theft of the money***

In the Collins, there is an example:

> Still, for those flashes of genius, you can ***forgive him anything***.

So it is right to say "forgive somebody something".

How to understand “for” here? Why not say "She'd find a way to forgive him the theft of the money"?

Answer (score 1):

"For", when it is present, is followed by the thing which is being excused (the topic of forgiveness).

As you suggest,

*She'd find a way to forgive him for the theft of the money*

means the same as

*She'd find a way to forgive him the theft of the money*

and both are equally correct.

As the topic of forgiveness increases in length, the first form tends to be preferred because it is easier to parse.

Consider the following example

*He forgave her her constant infidelity and devious ways, and the two continued to live together happily*

*He forgave her for her constant infidelity and devious ways, and the two continued to live together happily*

The first form makes it harder to determine where the topic of forgiveness ends, which makes the sentence more confusing.  Even the "double her" is potentially confusing, even for native English speakers.

Answer (score -1):

The [example in Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/forgive) is perfect. It shows *v,n,n* there as a structure. Other structures include *v*, *v, n*, *v n + for.*

The structure `forgive somebody something` is absolutely fine.

> The word [*forgive*'s](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/forgive) example: She'd forgive him anything

Why is *for* here? - We just have *to remember that way.* That's what I as a non-native do.